# XFCE window switching and tiling is not working for every window

Tags: window, xfce, alt-tab, tiles

I recently switched from Gnome (Ubuntu) to XFCE (Xubuntu) and noticed a problem (I am pretty sure that this had worked in the beginning but not anymore).

Some windows - and I can not figure out why these windows make problems - are not in the normal window switching cycle (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>) and it is also not possible to "tile" them. I set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to this actions and it is working for all other windows.

The windows I currently have trouble with are

- Slack
- Cypress

I guessed that all Electron based Windows have these troubles but this is not the case. I can start a fresh Electron with `npx elecotron` and I am able to cycle to it and also to tile it[[image: App Switcher]

Also, the icons of the not-working windows are looking different. Here is the icon from Slack
[image: Slack Icon]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have the same issue with Slack. I first noticed just a few days ago, I am pretty sure that it was working normally in the past.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I am using Xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I am glad that I am not the only one with that problem so has nothing to do with my system settings

Comment: Same with slack in Xubuntu 19.04.

Comment: I have the same issue in Linux Mint 19.1 xfce

Answer (score 2):

I contacted the Slack support regarding the window-switching issue.  They are already aware of it and working on a fix.  For the meantime (and possibly for other applications with the same issue), they mentioned the following workaround:

1. Execute the following command

   ```
   xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
   ```
2. Then click on the Slack window

This brings back the normal behaviour for that window until you restart the application (i.e. needs to be repeated after every restart).

Comment: This works somehow but not totally right. The Icon is still not the "right" window icon but a default one but the window appears again in the app switcher. Thanks for sharing. 

Does this bug belongs to slack or should it be fixed in xorg or xfce?
Because slack is only one application where this bug happens. cypres.io is another one

Comment: @thopaw Unfortunately, I don't know where the actual bug is located, I just got the response from the Slack support that "[they're] working on it". The missing icon might be an other, unrelated issue. I remember, that I had this already before the window-switching issue started. I only reported the switching-issue, when contacting the support, I should probably have mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: Today I got a Slack update that seems to fix the window-switching problem, so this workaround is not necessary anymore (at least for Slack).

Comment: same for me. But there is still the problem with other applications like cypress.io. The workaround with `xprop` works for these applications also.